# Faulty maximization state of a Firefox window at startup

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-gnome

Once in a while after a restart Firefox starts in this faulty state when half of the window is black and the buttons respond only after hovering the mouse to the top of the black area rather than on the buttons themselves. It is as if the window is partly maximized and partly not. Is this a Gnome bug or Firefox bug? Has it been reported anywhere?

Versions are Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-135-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:38:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and Firefox 85.0 (64-bit).

[image: buggy window]

Comment: What do you mean by "after a restart"? Do you mean restarting from a suspend where Firefox was previously running full screen? Or a fresh bootup and you have some sort of script or startup item to start Firefox automatically? Or a fresh bootup and you are then manually starting Firefox? I have a PC with a Firefox startup item and sometimes get something similar on a fresh bootup. Perhaps it's the same issue. I see a Firefox window in bottom-left of screen which takes up about 75% of the screen but is not full screen. I can't click on anything or close it and end up doing a `killall firefox`

Comment: I see it after fresh bootup / reboot when starting FF for the first time.

Comment: Still happens in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Firefox is started from the Startup Applications when iI log in. The window seems to be in the lower left corner of the screen but buttons and tabs are located at the top, which can be seen when typing the Alt-key. F11 (full screen) creates havoc. Only remedy: Alt-F4 and restart FF.

Comment: Still happens on Ubuntu 20.04.4 - but only if firefox is started via the `.config/autostart/*.desktop` mechanism, and can be worked around by editing that file to prepend a `sleep 10`.